# weird force close in creating socket

Tags: android, sockets

i'm working on an app that using Sockets but my app cannot create a socket cause of force close. i read many of similar question but that doesn't help me.
i don't really know whats wrong with my codes.
any help?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   Socket sck = null;
   boolean cflag = false;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ConnectionThread()).start();
        if(cflag)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   class ConnectionThread implements Runnable
   {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sck = new Socket("192.168.1.101",6789);
                if(sck.isConnected())cflag=true;
                else cflag = false;
            }
            catch(IOException ioex){}
        }
    }
}
```

also i added permission to my Manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Have a look at exception stacktrace in logcat. Also in your catch block, log the exception trace.

Comment: `cannot create a socket cause of force close` means you are getting an Exception. The first thing to do when that happens is have a look on the LogCat.